# Extracting information from XML using R

Tags: xml, r, xpath

I am trying to extract the date information from the following html code using R and xpathSApply:

```
                                                            </td>
                    </tr>
                                            <tr
                        data-row-id="1363827503"
                                                        class="future "
                        data-lat-from="-33.946098"
                        data-lon-from="151.1772"
                        data-lat-to="33.94252"
                        data-lon-to="-118.406998"
                        data-name-from="Sydney Kingsford Smith Airport"
                        data-name-to="Los Angeles International Airport"
                        data-date="2015-03-23"
                        data-flight=""
                        data-flight-number="VA1"
                    >
```

Here is the code in R I have tried:

```
library(XML)
url<- "http://www.flightradar24.com/data/flights/va1/"
info<- htmlTreeParse(url, useInternalNodes=T)
xpathSApply(info, "//data-date", xmlValue)
```

This returns: list()

I would like it to return: 2015-03-23

Answer (score 2):

This is the part of the document you are interested in:

```
<tr
    data-row-id="1363827503"
    class="future "
    data-lat-from="-33.946098"
    data-lon-from="151.1772"
    data-lat-to="33.94252"
    data-lon-to="-118.406998"
    data-name-from="Sydney Kingsford Smith Airport"
    data-name-to="Los Angeles International Airport"
    data-date="2015-03-23"
    data-flight=""
    data-flight-number="VA1"
>
```

As you can see, `data-date` is not an element, it is an attribute of a `tr` element. Use `//tr/@data-date` as the XPath expression to retrieve the `data-date` attribute.

But note that there are multiple `data-date` attributes in this document. To only retrieve a single attribute, you also need a way to identify a specific row, for instance with

```
//tr[@data-row-id="1363827503"]/@data-date
```

The ID `1363827503` occurs only once in this document and is therefore a unique identifier for this `tr` element.

Comment: Hi Mathias, thank you for your help.  I have tried the following code and got an error message:library(XML)
url<- "http://www.flightradar24.com/data/flights/qf1"
html<- htmlTreeParse(url, useInternalNodes=T)
xpathSApply(html, "//tr/@data-date", XMLAttributeValue) and i get the following error message: Error in xpathApply.XMLInternalDocument(doc, path, fun, ..., namespaces = namespaces,  : 
  object 'XMLAttributeValue' not found  I have tried a few other iterations but still could not make it work.  Any suggestions?

Comment: @user4685747;  Do you just want `xpathSApply(html, '//tr/@data-date')`